# Pandas: number of days elapsed since a certain date

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a 'date' column with ~200 elements in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

I want to compute the number of days elapsed since 2001-11-25 for each of those elements and add a column of those numbers of elapsed days to the dataframe.

I know of the to_datetime() function but can't figure out how to make this happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your time values are in your index, you can just do this:

```
import pandas

x = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start='2014-01-01', end='2014-01-06', freq='30T')
df = pandas.DataFrame(index=x, columns=['time since'])

basedate = pandas.Timestamp('2011-11-25')
df['time since'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.name.to_datetime() - basedate).days, axis=1)
```

If they're in a column, do:

```
df['time since'] = df['datetime_column'].apply(lambda x: (x.name.to_datetime() - basedate).days)
```

Comment: no need for apply ; you can directly subtract a Timestamp from a column to yield a timedelta64 dtype

Answer (score 10):

In accordance with Jeff's comment, here's a correction to the second (and most relevant) part of the accepted answer:

```
df['time since'] = (df['datetime_column'] - basedate).dt.days
```

The subtraction yields a series of type [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html), which can then be represented as days.

In some case you might need to pass the original column through [`pd.to_datetime(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first.